# Erase fields when application goes back to foreground

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm a very beginner in iOS developpment. What I what to do is to delete the content of 2 fields (login and password) when application moves to foregroung after being in background.
To be clear: if a user put the application in foreground and is on the login screen, fields corrsponding to login and password should be empty.

What I have done: I have add a listener to the AppDelegate file that is detecting well background/foreground actions. Here is the code:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    @try {
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;
    UIViewController *cont = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:[navigationController viewControllers].count - 1];

        if ([cont isKindOfClass:[LoginScreenController class]]){
            NSLog(@"[AppDelegate] ok, we're on login screen");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"[AppDelegate] No, we're not");
        }
    }
    @catch(NSException *exp)
    {
        NSLog(@"[AppDelegate] Fail: %@",exp);
    }
}
```

But when executing the code, I reach an issue linked to BaseRootView... First, do I proceed the appropriate way and then, how to do what I want to do? That's to say, how to erease the fields (I have a function to do this in the LoginController class, so how to call it prperly?)

Thanks !

Comment: Please add the method in `LoginScreenController`, that resets the field

Comment: Also what happens when user logged in to the application and goes to background ? do you want to logout the user?

Comment: can you not erase your login credential when LoginController called viewWillDisappear?

Comment: No, user is not logged in, just on the login screen with 2 textfields to fill, and I want these to be reset. @Idindu, that function will be triggered on "background putting"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code in

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

You should use this method instead of

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

when you update user interface this is what this method is for.
Hope this help.

// EXTENDED
Can you try put this code to UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(updateUI)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

And add this code to AppDelegate:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}
```

and add:

```
-(void)updateUI
{
    //Add code to update ui
}
```

Comment: Even when I do so I have the exception "BaseRootViewController unrecognize selector sent to instance 0x...."

Comment: did you setup your rootviewcontroller?

Comment: @Derbie see extended post and try apply the code instead of existing one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's ok now

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by posting a notification. Here in the place of yourFunctionName write your function name which is to erase the fields

In login view controller write this following code.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{

self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) 
{
    // Custom initialization
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(yourFunctionName) name:@"removeText" object:nil];
}
return self;
}
```

Now post a notification in applicationWillEnterForeground method.

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"removeText" object:nil];
}
```

Hope this helps you.